# Jquery looped array selectors with custom element ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Going through the other posts i must either have something wrong with my code or my logic is fundamentally flawed.

So what happens is i have a series of array elements that get called/written, these array elements need to have sub elements modified by java script.

Everything was workign before i needed to add an array i.e i was using a single element selector ID for the functions below and got the correct results. However after adding unique ID's in a loop it doesn't want to change.

So here's what happens, I have a separate div that is hidden. This prints out how many elements are in the array as its a PHP session variable. $Carray is a count function and works correctly.

```
<div class="Carray"><?php echo $Carray;?></div>
```

Then as the items are looped they add an array ID

```
<?php 
$arrayID = -1;
foreach($_SESSION['activity'] as $key){ 
foreach($key as $list){ 
$arrayID += 1;      
?>    
    <div id="subP_<?php echo $arrayID;?>" class="booking_action">-</div>
    <div id="booking_people_<?php echo $arrayID;?>" class="booking_people_number">
        <?php echo $list["i_quantity"] ?>
    </div>
    <div id="addP_<?php echo $arrayID;?>" class="booking_action">+</div>
<?php }} ?>
```

Then in Javascript i call a loop function that counts through however many $Carray elements there are and then corresponds the correct function actions to the correct div ID's

```
   //get the counted array variable and force as an int
    var js_var = parseInt($('.Carray').html(),10);

    // loop for however many array elements there are
    for (i = 0; i < js_var; i++){

    // get the amount of people from a field 
    var ppl_P =  parseInt($('#booking_people_'+i).html(),10);

    // subtract 1 person and then change the output to match the new people count 
    $("#subP_"+i).click(function() {
      if(ppl_P >= 2){
        ppl_P -= 1;
        $('#booking_people_'+i]).html(ppl_P);
      }
    });

    // Add 1 person and then change the output to match the new people count 
    $("#addP_"+i).click(function() {
        ppl_P += 1;
        $('#booking_people_'+i).html(ppl_P);
    });
    }
```

******************************  EDIT **********************

So based on Jimmi Elofsson answer which works beautifully, i want to expand this to effect elements that are not inside the parent/child selectors. The selector is '.booking_price_inner' which is another div stored elsewhere. I am assuming the line that needs the correct syntax is the marked line.

The '.booking_base_price' is within the parent/child element.

```
    $(".subPerson").click(function() {
    // Subtract Person 
    var subPeopleCount = getCurrentCountByPeopleItem($(this).parent()) - 1;
    $(this).parent().children('.booking_people_number').html(subPeopleCount>1 ? subPeopleCount : 1);
    //Change price
    var totalPriceS = subPeopleCount * getBasePrice($(this).parent());
    $(this).parent().children('.booking_price_inner').html(totalPriceS); <-------
});
$(".addPerson").click(function() {
    //Add person
    var addPeopeCount = getCurrentCountByPeopleItem($(this).parent()) + 1;
    $(this).parent().children('.booking_people_number').html(addPeopeCount);
    //Change price
    var totalPriceA = addPeopleCount * getBasePrice($(this).parent());
    $(this).parent().children('.booking_price_inner').html(totalPriceA); <------
});
// get the number of people in the specific array
function getCurrentCountByPeopleItem(peopleItem) {
    return parseInt(peopleItem.children('.booking_people_number').html());
}
//get the base price
function getBasePrice(peoplePrice){
     return parseInt(peoplePrice.children('.booking_base_price').html());
}
```

Markup

```
<div id="<?php echo $arrayID;?>" class="booking_people">
    <div class="booking_date_header">People:</div>
    <div class="subPerson booking_action">-</div>
    <div class="booking_people_number"><?php echo $list["i_quantity"] ?></div>
    <div class="addPerson booking_action">+</div>
    <div class="booking_base_price"><?php echo $list["i_base_price"] ?></div>
</div>
<div class=spacer></div>
<div class=cost>
    <div class=booking_price_inner></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you only have one .cost containing .booking_price_inner you could simply do `$('.cost > .booking_price_inner').html(totalPriceS);`

otherwise maybe if you put .cost .booking_price_inner inside the .booking_people div? and then `$(this).parent().find('.cost > .booking_price_inner').html(totalPriceS);`

later if you want to get total of all the items, a good start could be to use the forEach loop that I posted in the other comment :) good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works! Hypothetically if you had it deeply nested or somewhere completely  different what would be the best way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind, I did some changes in your code.

you could make your add/substract element use the same click function with the help of some DOM traversing. That way you wouldnt need the CArray to keep track of the buttons.

Javascript:

```
// subtract 1 person and then change the output to match the new people count  
$(".subPerson").click(function() {
    var subPeopleCount = getCurrentCountByPeopleItem($(this).parent()) - 1;// Substract by one.
    $(this).parent().children('.booking_people_number').html(subPeopleCount>1 ? subPeopleCount : 1);
});

// Add 1 person and then change the output to match the new people count 
$(".addPerson").click(function() {
    var addPeopeCount = getCurrentCountByPeopleItem($(this).parent()) + 1; // Increase by one.
    $(this).parent().children('.booking_people_number').html(addPeopeCount);
});

function getCurrentCountByPeopleItem(peopleItem) {
    return parseInt(peopleItem.children('.booking_people_number').html());
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$arrayID = -1;
foreach($_SESSION['activity'] as $key){ 
foreach($key as $list){ 
$arrayID += 1;      
?>
<div class="booking_people_item" id="<?php echo $arrayID;?>">
    <div class="subPerson booking_action">-</div>
    <div class="booking_people_number">
        <?php echo $list["i_quantity"] ?>
    </div>
    <div class="addPerson booking_action">+</div>
</div>
<?php }} ?>
```

I added a div wrapper around your elements called booking_people_item.

Comment: Incredibly elegent, a much more pragmatic way of approaching the problem. Much appreciated

Comment: So trying to build on this, how would you go about adding functionality that took values from a child of another/different parent?

Comment: @Paddy you could do so by looking for the other parent by id, first of I should tell that you should have something more than a simple integer in the id field of the div for this to work. lets say:  

`<div class="booking_people_item" id="id-<?php echo $arrayID;?>">`
  
let then say that you want to get the element with id 5 for example:  
`getCurrentCountByPeopleItem( $('div#id-5') );`
  
you could also go trough them all, like this.  

`$( ".booking_people_item" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( getCurrentCountByPeopleItem( $(this) ) );
});`

Comment: perfect, that solves that potential issue. Sorry i was a bit vague with my question. what i meant was a completely different parent/child structure, i posted an edit on the original code.

Answer (score 0):

from what I see - you're definig click functions in a loop. Those click functions have a reference to a ppl_P variable. When you define the click, it seems OK. But when the click is triggered, the ppl_P variable is already set to the value from loops last iteration. So, whenever you call that click function, it always has the same result, doesn't it?

The proper way to do it would be to pass this ppl_P variable as a parameter, so you don't have a reference to a variable that was already changed in the other scope. Something like:

```
function addClickFunction(i, ppl_P){

$("#subP_"+i).click(function() {
  if(ppl_P >= 2){
    ppl_P -= 1;
    $('#booking_people_'+i]).html(ppl_P);
  }
});

// Add 1 person and then change the output to match the new people count 
$("#addP_"+i).click(function() {
    ppl_P += 1;
    $('#booking_people_'+i).html(ppl_P);
});

}
```

And then use this function inside the loop:

```
var ppl;
for (i = 0; i < js_var; i++){
    ppl =  parseInt($('#booking_people_'+i).html(),10);
    addClickFunction(i, ppl);
}
```

This hasn't been tested, but I'm pretty sure you'll get the point :)

Comment: Yep, i understand the logic flaw i had in my code based on your answer. Didn't get a chance to implement it fully, but seems to be the correct way to approach it.